# Abessive case in Finnish

Tags: finnish

Abessive case (-tta/ttä) in Finnish is used to mean "without"/"not doing".
In Finnish if a statement is negative partitive case will be required.
Examples: "Minulla ei ole pallo**a**." (I do not have a ball). "Minä en osta pallo**a**." - I do not buy a ball.

I am wanting to know whether the same applies for sentences using abessive case and the partitive case is required with abessive.

As an example: "Uskaltaako **tätä** **korttia** olla katsomatta?" (Does one dare not to look at this card?)

Is the noun "tämä kortti" (this card) given in partitive because of ablative *or* is it because the verb "katsoa" itself needs partitive. Could the accusative case be used instead with abessive. For example "Hän uskalsi olla katsomatta ***kortit***" versus "Hän uskalsi olla katsomatta ***korteja***" (He dared not to look at the cards).

Comment: Unfortunately, language-specific grammar questions like this one are off-topic here. I say unfortunately, because I think this is a really good question, and I don’t know the answer. I don’t know if you can say _katsomatta kortit_ to mean ‘not looking at (all) the cards’ and _katsomatta korteja_ ‘not looking at (some of) cards’.

Comment: Looking at the closest thing I have to a proper Finnish grammar, the examples would appear to indicate that the abessive does govern the partitive in its direct object: _Hän lähti ulos sanomatta **sanaakaan**_, _Yritin olla herättämättä **häntä**_, etc.

Comment: Indeed, Fred Karlsson's grammar (which I only have in German) says in § 76.5: the object stands in partitive (_Olutta juomatta en pärjää_), and the subject in genitive or as possesive suffix, if it is a personal pronoun (_Kalle teki sen (meidän) tietämättämme_).

Comment: @JanusBahsJacquet Hey, I kind of posted this question here because I couldn't think of a better place to ask it, but wondered if this was the correct forum for it and noticed that there aren't any Finnish learner here. What is this purpose of this language community (i.e. if not for specific language questions) and could you direct me to a better option if you know of one?

Comment: @lily23 This site is more limited in scope, dealing with the linguistics as such – that is, the analysis of language structure itself, rather than any individual implementation of language structure (e.g., X-bar theory, generative grammar, etc.). I personally don’t think good language-specific questions should be considered off-topic, but the community as a whole has decided that they are. Unfortunately, there aren’t any better SE sites for languages that don’t have a dedicated site of their own. It would be nice if there were a stack for language questions in general.

Comment: @JanusBahsJacquet I notice that German has its own site. Would it be worthwhile to establish a Finnish language site for questions like this? I don't know anything about what that would involve, but I would use such a site definitely.

Comment: @lily23 Probably not; I don’t think it would get enough traffic to pass. New sites can be suggested at [area51.se], but it’s a long process that requires, among other things, establishing a community and moderators, showing a certain level of activity, etc., before a site is considered for graduation to actual siteness.

Comment: @JanusBahsJacquet okay fair enough. The \LearnFinnish reddit page somewhat fills this need anyway, but more complex grammatical questions tend to be difficult to get an answer for even there.